# How to change the behaviour of <c-w>v?

Tags: key-bindings

Say that I have only one window on the screen.
When I hit `<c-w>v` I got a vertical split and the cursor jumps in the window on the right.
Instead, I want the cursor to stay in the left window after I run `<c-w>v`.

How to do that?

Comment: Only for `<C-w>v` or for other splitting scenarios as well?

Comment: It does not really matter as I use 99% of times <C-w>v. A solution for other scenarii is welcome anyway.

Comment: Here is one: don't `set splitright` in your `vimrc`.

Answer (score 1):

I would introduce the following map:

```
nnoremap <C-w>v <C-w>v<C-w>p
```

Comment: If the solution fit your need maybe could you accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting button. It allow the question to rest :-)